# SetState of an object with multiple items

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to set the state of object with the following characteristics:

```
interface GridValue {
    control: string;
    rowIndex: number;
    cellIndex: number;
}
```

And my component state contains the following:

```
interface ComponentState {
    results: InChartModel[];
    loading: boolean;
    control: string;
    modalValue: GridValue[];
}
```

But when I attempt to set the state with the following code, it doesn't work (types of property "modalValue" are incompatible):

```
handleClick(e: any) {
    const rindex: number = e.currentTarget.rowIndex;
    const cindex: number = e.target.cellIndex;
    const grid: any = e.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode;
    const ctrl: string = grid.rows[rindex].cells[0].innerText;
    const metric: string = grid.rows[rindex].cells[1].innerText;
    this.setState({
        modalValue: {
            "control": ctrl,
            "rowIndex": rindex,
            "cellIndex": cindex
        }
    })
    this.props.getInptModal(ctrlType, metric);
}
```

Is this the rough idea of how to properly do this? I've been able to set the state with single variables but I'm struggling with updating it with an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You described `modalValue` as an array but you are setting it as an object. 
Either change its type to `GridValue` or use an array on `setState`:

```
this.setState({
  modalValue: [{
    control: ctrl,
    rowIndex: rindex,
    cellIndex: cindex
  }]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`modalValue` is expecting an **array** of `GridValue`, not just a `GridValue`. You can either pass in an array of `GridValue` object(s) or just set your `ComponentState`'s `modalValue` to a `GridValue`:

```
interface ComponentState {
    results: InChartModel[];
    loading: boolean;
    control: string;
    modalValue: GridValue; // not an array
}
```